# Label indentation of enumerate and itemize don't line up

Tags: enumerate, indentation, itemize, enumitem, parindent

When using `itemize` and `enumerate` and setting the same `labelindent`, there are different results. The number doesn't line up with the paragraph indentation. This issue is exaggerated when reaching ten items.

[image]

**MWE:**

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=32.5mm, right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
    \setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}
\usepackage{enumitem}
    \setlist[itemize]{labelindent=\parindent, label={--}}
    \setlist[enumerate]{labelindent=\parindent}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1][1-3]
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Test
    \end{enumerate}

    \lipsum[1][1-3]
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Test
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the place of `labelindent=`, you should use `wide=` which adds the left-alignment of the labels. There remains a tiny difference in alignment (< 0.2pt), which can be seen only using a large zoom, and is due to the slightly different side-bearings of glyphs.

Demonstration, adding an \fbox around the labels:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[left=32.5mm, right=25mm, top=25mm, bottom=20mm]{geometry}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.1pt}
\setlength{\fboxsep}{0.pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}
    \setlist[itemize]{wide=\parindent, label=\fbox{--}}
    \setlist[enumerate]{wide=\parindent, label = \fbox{\arabic*}}

\begin{document}

   \fbox{L}orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut,
placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Test
\item Another test 
    \end{enumerate}

    \fbox{L}orem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Ut purus elit, vestibulum ut,
placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis. Curabitur dictum gravida mauris.
    \begin{itemize}
        \item A compulsive test
    \end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

First, the label is by default typeset *flush right* in a box of width `\labelwidth` that starts at `\labelindent` from the left margin (as shown below, this can be changed with, for instance, `align=left`). But this assumes that you give `enumitem` a way to satisfy the various constraints.

As the `enumitem` manual explains, there are five horizontal length parameters linked by one linear relation:

```latex
\leftmargin + \itemindent = \labelindent + \labelwidth + \labelsep
```

By default, `enumitem` does `labelindent=!` which means that it computes `\labelindent` from the other parameters; however, in both of your examples, you explicitly set `\labelindent`, so `enumitem` must be able to compute another parameter from the others, and you need to specify which one. For instance, you can use `leftmargin=*`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\setlength{\parindent}{1.5em}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\setlist[itemize]{labelindent=\parindent, align=left, leftmargin=*,
                  label={--}}
\setlist[enumerate]{labelindent=\parindent, align=left, leftmargin=*}

\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1][1-3]
    \begin{enumerate}
        \item Test
    \end{enumerate}

    \lipsum[1][1-3]
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Test
    \end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Zoom with vertical rule:

[image]

Note that this is explained in the documentation of the `labelindent` option (and `\labelindent` length parameter):

> `labelindent=〈length〉`
>   `\labelindent`
>   This parameter is added in `enumitem` for the blank space from the margin of the enclosing list/text to the left edge of the label box. This means there is a redundancy because one of the parameters depends on the others, i.e., it has to be computed from the other values, as described below. By default, the computed value is `labelindent`, even if explicitly set with some value (it defaults to `0pt`). So, if you are setting it to some value, very likely you want to set some other parameter to `!` or `*`, because otherwise it is ignored.

Comment: @Johannes Your question doesn't mention *at all* that you wanted line wrapping in the items to use the outer margin on the left. Moreover, the red line from your picture could quite easily be interpreted as meaning that wrapped lines from items should *not* cross it. Unaccepting an answer based on requirements completely absent from the question is... questionable.